# How to pop an ajax to play a video

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a search engine that when you search a video it will display a list of url for example in youtube. and when i clicked it .  it will redirect me to the URL. But I only want to click it and it will display a popwindow or fancy box that will fetch the video only and right away I will watch the video. How will I get only the video? not the URL of the website?

The search engine that I got is a sphider search engine. I'm just new in programming. Is there an ajax or api or jquery that when i clicked the URL it will popup a window or a box and will get the embed video and will watch it there?

For example:

i got this url in my list. how will this be a popup, and will only get the video?

[**http://www.kumby.com/beast-saga-episode-4/***](http://www.kumby.com/beast-saga-episode-4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a pop up but that should do it:

```
$('#video-container').html(
    '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yQaAGmHNn9s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
);
```

You mentioned fancybox, if you meant the jquery plugin:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yQaAGmHNn9s">Video</a>
```

Comment: ok i'll try this. thank you very much that you response for this. i thought i will got a downvote. im just a new programmer :)